# How to have 2 different ID's in the same cell on the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I have 2 different data coming in from javascript and I would like to show both data in the same cell on the same row

HTML code:

```
  <td>
  <div class="rcelldata">
  <div id="r_laps"></div>
  <div id="r_dfs" ></div>
  </td>
```

Results are:
data for r_laps
data for r_dfs

I want
r_laps r_dfs

Bonus points, how to add parenthesis around the second data
r_laps (r_dfs)

Thanks in advance

tried many forms of

Comment: Apparently, your question didn't format as intended. The `div`s are block level and will be stacked. If you want side-by-side, either add `display: flex` to the `rcelldata` rule or try using an inline element such as `span`. I'm not knowledgeable about JavaScript but I imagine the parenthesis can be appended to the value. It would have been helpful to see the JS you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript in a way like

```
    var r_laps = document.getElementById("r_laps");
    var r_dfs = document.getElementById("r_dfs");

    r_laps.innerHTML = r_laps_recieved
    r_dfs.innerHTML = rr_dfs_recieved
```

if you want paranthesis around you can use

```
  r_dfs.innerHTML = `(${rr_dfs_recieved})`
```